# Can't change rails engine middleware

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rake, rails-engines

I forced Rails Engine middleware to use my Rack class.

```
class Engine < Rails::Engine
  initializer 'Logging' do |app|
    app.config.middleware.use Rack::LogMid # my rake class
  end
end
```

It works for me when I run my rails server as normal process (rails s). But, it's not working when I run my server as daemon process (rails s -d)

Can you please anyone correct me, if i'm doing anything wrong.

Thanks.

Comment: Perhaps this instead?

    class Engine < Rails::Engine
      middleware.use Rack::LogMid
    end

Comment: @rhodee thanks. It's not working..

Comment: Rails engines configs run before `application.rb` for main app loads. Is the middleware in the Gemfile of the Engine or the parent?